# warning: control reaches end of non-void function - c++

Tags: c++, funções

Estou fazendo uma função para retornar o máximo e estou tendo problemas...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    if(a > b){
        if (a > c){
            if(a > d){
                return a; //
            }

            else return d; //
        }
    }
    else if(b > c){
        if(b > d){
            return b; //
         }

         else return d; //
    }


    else if(c > d){
        return c; //
    }
    else return d; //


}

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;

    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);

    return 0;
}
```

Por que estou tendo este aviso?

```
control reaches end of non-void function
```

Comment: Se o primeiro `if (a > b)` entrar e o `if (a > c)` de dentro não passar, sua função contém comportamento indefinido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A outra resposta já fala qual o erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/266305/64969). O Maniero dá uma solução viável, mas talvez não a desejada. Vou destrinchar aqui onde está faltando e o que está coberto. Nas condições, vou colocar letras sequenciais para ficar mais fácil mencionar.

Para mencionar que a condição em `A` resulta em verdade, a condição de `B` também mas a de `E` resulta em falso, vou usar a notação `A,B,~E`, onde o tilde `~` indica que a comparação deu falso.

```
if (A) {
  if (D) {
    if (E) {
      return a
    } else {
      return d
    }
  }
} else if (B) {
  if (F) {
    return b
  } else {
    return d
  }
} else if (C) {
  return c
} else {
  return d
}
```

Note que, caso as condições sejam `A,~D`, ele não alcançará nenhum `return`. Esse é o motivo de o compilador gerar um *warning*, pois ele está analisando essa forma.

Creio que a solução seria por um `else` para a condição `D` e colocar mais uma estrutura de `if-else` dentro do `~D`

Answer (score 3):

Existe um situação que não tem retorno e isso não pode acontecer, a função tem que retornar algo em todas as situações, provavelmente é só retirar o `else` no final e resolverá porque se todas condições falharem ele executará alguma coisa.

O código é muito confuso e tem outros problemas, assim que tiver tempo eu monto um melhor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Mas o else não garante que ele execute alguma coisa, quando todas as outas falham? No caso do exemplo, quando ele não retornar nenhum dos outros, ele deve retornar d.

Answer (score 1):

Por que você não usa um for ao invés dos vários ifs. Vai ficar menos confuso e menor.

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    int numbers[4]={a,b,c,d};
    int biggest=a;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        if(numbers[i]>biggest){ biggest=numbers[i]; }
    }
    return biggest;
}
```

Comment: Uma explicação é uso de memória. Sem falar que no seu `for` só se necessitam de 3 elementos, já que `a` é a priori

Comment: Verdade, porém não acho que a memoria seria um problema, depende de onde ele vai rodar esse código